# posgres query filter by date in format Mon Aug 24 14:16:00 GMT 2020

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a table of logs where data is being saved with format `Mon Aug 24 14:16:00 GMT 2020`  and I need to query the data that is between a date range.

I need something like

```
SELECT * FROM logs
WHERE
      log_date_time >= 'some-date-format'
  AND log_date_time <  'some-date-format';
```

the `log_date_time` is saved as a string. I tried using

```
select * from logs
WHERE log_date_time BETWEEN 'Mon Aug 05 2019' AND 'Mon Aug 24 17:54:37 GMT 2020';
```

But it is not working correclty, brings only  dates from day 17 and 24

How can I query this?

Comment: What is the data type of the date_time field?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I edited the question and corrected what I tried to explain (the datatype) is stored as a string. I think that this is saved from a Java backend making a new Date().toString()

Comment: Can you fix your Java code? The data type in the column should be `timestamptz` and the value should be passed as an instance of `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, not as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   logs
WHERE 
   log_date_time::timestamptz 
BETWEEN 
    'Mon Aug 05 2019 GMT'::timestamptz 
AND 
    'Mon Aug 24 17:54:37 GMT 2020'::timestamptz;
```

Where you convert the `log_date_time` to a `timestamp with time zone` and then do the same for the string datetime values you want to use as the date range.

Comment: using both strings with no time or adding 00:00:00 on the first date worked like a charm.